# What happens if you nest extern "C"?

Tags: c++, nested, extern

It looks like nesting extern "C" is legal. For example:

```
extern "C" extern "C" void foo();
```

The second `extern "C"` is essentially ignored. Is that guaranteed by the C++ standard? Where?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, but it's actually the first `extern "C"` that's ignored. To quote the standard [[dcl.link]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.link#5):

> Linkage specifications nest. When linkage specifications nest, the
> innermost one determines the language linkage.

Comment: you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Sorry, I answered my own question. :) I need the reputation! Got tired of not being able to vote or comment.

Comment: ROFL! Good for you!

Comment: @orochryden In that case, you can post the answer at the same time, as the question. There should be an additional box at the bottom of the question filling page, for the answer.

Comment: Damn. What should I do with this info?

Comment: @Ashe the human If by "info" you mean the answer I posted, then maybe I can explain the motivation for the question: I was using a preprocessor macro in a way that led to a nested extern "C" and I was curious if that's actually legal.